# Parse \u00 string android

Tags: android

I want to parse a string which is encoded in \u00 characters (like \u003e, \u003c etc) into normal string so that I can load it in webview. May I know how to parse it? I searched a lot on internet, but all results were php related.

EDIT:  The string is here: http://pastie.org/8950227

I want to display it in webview, but it is displaying plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data looks like it is a valid JSON string literal. You can use `JSONTokener` to parse it:

```
String data = ...;
String parsed = (String)new JSONTokener(data).nextValue();
```